# Subview on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, subview

I've added a subview to my table view controller. The subview has three subviews (a close button, a toolbar used to blur the main view, and a table view). The problem is that you are still able to see a bit of the main view at the bottom of the subview. I have tried initializing the subview with this frame, `contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];`, and that fixes the issue, but then if I scroll down on the parent view's table view, the subview can't be seen. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
- (void)showMenu
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    UIColor *kfbBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0f green:77.0/255.0f blue:139.0/255.0f alpha:1];

    contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
    contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIButton *closeMenuButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [closeMenuButton setFrame:CGRectMake(275, 10, 40, 40)];
    [closeMenuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeMenuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    blurredView = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:contentView.bounds];
    [blurredView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [blurredView setBarTintColor:kfbBlue];

    MenuTableViewController *menu = [[MenuTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    menu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:contentView];
    [contentView addSubview:blurredView];
    [self addChildViewController:menu];
    [contentView addSubview:menu.view];
    [contentView addSubview:closeMenuButton];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a picture to help visualize this? Also is there a reason you're using a TableViewController and adding these views as subviews to the tableview instead of using a ViewController that implements <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>?

Comment: @LyricalPanda, I've added a pic.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a TableViewController instead of a UIViewController if you're playing around the with the views/subivews?

Comment: MenuTableViewController is actually a subclass of UIViewController. I just didn't change the name.